pdf package is not working in Flutter web hosting
I used the pdf package in my Flutter web project. It is completely working while I run it in debug or release mode, but when the web is deployed, it is not working. We can see it is clickable, but nothing happens after clicking. 
Currently, when I click on the button, I can see it is clicked, but nothing happens. I want to generate a pdf while clicking, and this problem only arises when the web is deployed.
I tried to put this code in the index.html file, but nothing happened.
<script type="text/javascript">
  pdfjsLib.GlobalWorkerOptions.workerSrc =
    "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/pdfjs-dist@3.4.120/build/pdf.worker.min.js";
  pdfRenderOptions = {
    // where cmaps are downloaded from
    cMapUrl: "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/pdfjs-dist@3.4.120/cmaps/",
    // The cmaps are compressed in the case
    cMapPacked: true,
    // any other options for pdfjsLib.getDocument.
    // params: {}
  };
</script>


Please also share the current behaviour and expected behaviour so that ppl can help.

I had used a font in my code as 
  static getGujaratiFont() async {
      final font = await rootBundle.load("fonts/NotoSansGujarati.ttf");
      gujaratiFont = pw.Font.ttf(font);

}
and my path in pubspec.yaml file is
  assets:
    - assets/fonts/NotoSansGujarati.ttf

so, there is 'rootBundle' is take automatic assets while debugging web but when web is deployed i have to set path in my font as rootBundle.load("assets/fonts/NotoSansGujarati.ttf"); then it is working
